# How to make text overflow visible for input element in HTML?

Tags: html, css

How can I make the input's value in the following piece of code entirely visible (in an 'overflow: visible' fashion)?

```
<input type="submit" value="XXXXX" style="width: 5px;">
```

Comment: Can't you just remove `width: 5px` ?

Comment: What would be the use case for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you can wrap it in a div , then it's possible to use ::before and ::after css elements. 
you can attach the desired text to that pseudo-element .
an input field does not accept pseudo-element .

```css
.a {
  position:relative; 
  width:5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.a::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: 'xxxxx';
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100px;
  z-index:10
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
<input type="submit" value="XXXXX" class="a">
<div>
```